# Is there a Python library or module with I can draw letters and get X,Y coordinates of line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I want to draw text, which I already can do using turtle or tkinter, but I also want to find the X,Y coordinates of line as it advances so I can redraw them on another program which only draws lines using X,Y coordinates of points.
Thanks

Comment: You could convert the text to an image and read the black pixels

Comment: yes, but that would be very computationally expensive. I need to do it on runtime, eg as turtle (python module) draws it also gives its path coordinates in terms of X and Y (in mm or inches)

Comment: I don't imagine that'd be possible to be fair, especially if it's got anti-aliasing. I don't know much about fonts but I know it's not as simple as printing a black image on a background. In your shoes I'd either draw each letter once separately and cache the pixels used (then figure out the words from that), or just come up with a custom font implementation.